# Convert timestamp timezone in Logstash for output index name

Tags: ruby, indexing, elasticsearch, timezone, logstash

In my scenario, the "timestamp" of the syslog lines Logstash receives is in UTC and we use the event "timestamp" in the Elasticsearch output:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        embedded => false
        host => localhost
        port => 9200
        protocol => http
        cluster => 'elasticsearch'
        index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

My problem is that at UTC midnight, Logstash sends log to different index before the end of the day in out timezone (GMT-4 => America/Montreal) and the index has no logs after 20h (8h PM) because of the "timestamp" being UTC.

We've done a work arround to convert the timezone but we experience a significant performance degradation:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            # Create a new field with string value of the UTC event date
            "timestamp_zoned" => "%{@timestamp}"
        }
    }

    date {
        # Parse UTC string value and convert it to my timezone into a new field
        match => [ "timestamp_zoned", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        timezone => "America/Montreal"
        locale => "en"
        remove_field => [ "timestamp_zoned" ]
        target => "timestamp_zoned_obj"
    }

    ruby {
        # Output the zoned date to a new field
        code => "event['index_day'] = event['timestamp_zoned_obj'].strftime('%Y.%m.%d')"
        remove_field => [ "timestamp_zoned_obj" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        embedded => false
        host => localhost
        port => 9200
        protocol => http
        cluster => 'elasticsearch'
        # Use of the string value
        index => "syslog-%{index_day}"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this config?

Comment: The `@timestamp` field is supposed to be in UTC. Other tools (like Kibana and Elasticsearch Curator) rely on this and you shouldn't change it unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the optimize config, please have a try and test for the performance.

You no need to use `mutate` and `date` plugin. Use `ruby` plugin directly.

```
input {
    stdin {
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    event['index_day'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
            "
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Example output:

```
{
       "message" => "test",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-30T05:27:06.310Z",
          "host" => "BEN_LIM",
     "index_day" => "2015.03.29"
}
```

Comment: Ohh thanks! I didn't know that `localtime` could be called without any parameters.

Comment: Why am I getting error: Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `localtime'

Comment: Update for more modern versions of Logstash:
`event.set('localdate', event.get('@timestamp').time.localtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z'))`

Answer (score 3):

In [logstash version 5.0 and later](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/breaking-changes.html), you can use this:

```
filter{
ruby {
        code => "event.set('index_day', event.get('[@timestamp]').time.localtime.strftime('%Y%m%d'))"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.5.0, we can convert timestamp by local timezone for the index name. Here is my configuration:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event['index_day'] = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => localhost
        index => "thrall-%{index_day}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Logstash Version 5.0.2，The API was modified. We can convert timestamp by local timezone for the index name. Here is my configuration:

```
filter { 
   ruby { 
       code => "event['index_day'] = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')" 
   } 
}
```

Comment: filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event['index_day'] = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Similar use case - but using the [logstash file output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html) and writing files dated by the local time of the *arrival of the event*.
Verified on `logstash version 7.12`.

Adapted from [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/create-daily-indices-based-on-local-timezone/204330), mainly zero padding the offset hours. NB! If your offset has half hours you will need to adjust accordingly.

```json
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
        require 'tzinfo'
        tz = 'Europe/Oslo'
        offset = TZInfo::Timezone.get(tz).current_period.utc_total_offset / (60*60)
        event.set('[@metadata][local_date]',
                  event.get('@timestamp').time.localtime(
                      sprintf('+%02i:00', offset.to_s)
                  ).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
        "
    }   
    if ([agent][type] == "filebeat") {
        mutate {
            add_field => ["file_path", "%{[host][name]}_%{[log][file][path]}.%{[@metadata][local_date]}"]
        }  
    } else {   
        mutate {
            add_field => ["file_path", "%{[agent][hostname]}_%{[agent][type]}.%{[@metadata][local_date]}"]
        }
    }
}
```