# Modify a timezone in Logstash

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, timezone, logstash

I have logstash getting data from a MySQL table. The data contains a timestamp field that is saved in the timezone of the MySQL DB, that is UTC. So if I save "10:27:15" as the time from my app, the row in the DB contains "08:27:15Z" since I am in Europe/Rome tz that is offset 2 hours.
When I get it into logstash/es with MySQL plugin the record is "de-zoned" again, and my data contains "06:27:15Z".
I'm trying to apply the correct TZ to my data so that in ES I get "08:27:15Z". 
I tried [Convert timestamp timezone in Logstash for output index name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302444/convert-timestamp-timezone-in-logstash-for-output-index-name), that is duplicating a field and re-parsing it again applying the TZ.
The problem is that I get a "_dateparsefailure" parsing
`"tztstamp" => "2016-03-31T06:17:47.000Z"`
using
`match => ["tztstamp", "ISO8601"]`
That is the correct format. I tried also other formats built for the purpose to no avail.
Server runs with the Europe/Rome timezone. "@timezone" field is automatically populated with correct UTC time (that is now-2h).
Any ideas how to have my time correct into ES?
To add a "visual" example, this in the DB
[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNPG.jpg) 
becomes
[Logstash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rjC6.png)
if I don't do anything

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the logstash is running on machine with "Europe/Rome"  timezone. 
In your example the `tstamp` (2016-03-31 08:17:47)  field  do not have TimeZone Info, so logstash  thinks it in "Europe/Rome". 
To let  Logstash know about correct TimeZone you have to specify `timezone` option for `date` filter:

```
date {
    match => [ "tstamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "UTC"
}
```

Also  you are getting `_dateparsefailure` because of `tstamp` is not in ISO8601 format.

Comment: "2016-03-31T06:17:47.000Z" is ISO8601 indeed. The screenshot is from phpmyadmin.