# Convert Logstash @timestamp from UTC to Local and save as "Timestamp with timezone" datatype

Tags: postgresql, logstash, local, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

Logstash @timestamp is by default in UTC and of string type. I need it in Local and "timestamp with timezone" type. I save @timestamp into Postgres db, where table column holds "Timestamp with timezone" data type. If I try to directly save @timestamp value, I get error stating that @timestamp expression is string and table column expects "timestamp with timezone". Then I changed column's type to VARCHAR and output was successful but the value stored in table was UTC of course.

So, if @timestamp equals to "2017-06-15 12:31:54.916000" in UTC, in my Local it should be "2017-06-15 14:31:54.916000" because I'm UTC+2h.

How can I create new field in Logstash that will hold "timestamp with timezone" datatype and in my Local?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question [Convert timestamp timezone in Logstash for output index name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302444/convert-timestamp-timezone-in-logstash-for-output-index-name). I'm not a Ruby expert but I think it could help you.